# password hash and verify not work properly

Tags: php

Password hash not work properly in my script.

*Here my integration:*

**register.php**

```
    $password = password_hash(md5(sha1($_POST['password']) . $salt), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

*And here how i verify it:*

**Login.php**

```
    $password = md5(sha1($_POST['password']) . $salt);

    $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email'");
    $passw_hash = $check->fetch_assoc();
    if (password_verify($password, $passw_hash["password"])) {
        // LOGIN SUCCESSFULLY
    }
```

**My PHP version: 5.5**

Or if you have any other method to encrypt password let me know.

**UPDATE**

1- Modified password's column size to VARCHAR (250) from VARCHAR (60)

2- Removed all other encryptions like md5, sha1, and cleaning the code to protect password against sql injections.

***Example of hashed password:***

Pure TEXT: `google`

Hashed: `$2y$10$0Bd5Uv09Jg50QZZ4Iz7F2.WGV3MpYkScg9vuTONWmUCMYPJ3qDukC`

I insert a new member to my database with prepared statements using mysqli:

```
        $st = $mysqli->prepare("
                                    INSERT INTO
                                        accounts(
                                            username,
                                            password,
                                            date
                                        ) VALUES (
                                            ?,
                                            ?,
                                            ?
                                        )");
        $st->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $date);
        $st->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using `password_hash()` you do not want to use any additional hashing, so remove the `md5()` and `sha1()` functions.

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Furthermore, remove the functions from your login:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

By adding the other functions you're destroying the elements `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` need to do their jobs. Adding the two additional hashing mechanisms also don't make the hash any more secure.

Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

---

In addition [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: What do you mean by "not solved"? The important thing to note here is the  password_hash() can generate some very lengthy text (the current default is 60 characters), so making the field larger now will allow for the length needed. Secondly the PHP team is adding more algorithms to the method which means the hash can and will grow. We also do not want to limit our user's ability to use the password or passphrase of their choice. It's best to leave room for the changes. What size is the column in your database where you're storing the passwords?

Comment: My size is VARCHAR(60)

Comment: Even though that should work, make it larger. Can you share one of the hashes after you fixed the code?

Comment: You're also assuming your query is working. Are there any errors in your error logs? Can you post the markup for your login form?

Comment: Here an example of one of the hash: `$2y$10$0Bd5Uv09Jg50QZZ4Iz7F2.WGV3MpYkScg9vuTONWmUCMYPJ3qDukC` for password: `google`

Comment: And not that i modified size to VARCHAR(250).

Comment: @JackPanston can you update question with your updated code? Can you also show the `insert` you are using?

Comment: The hash looks OK now Jack. Can you add the code @chris85 is asking for?

Comment: Yes i just did that, you can check :)

Comment: Can you `print_r($passw_hash);` after you run the `SELECT` query and fetch the results?

Comment: I'm still not clear what actually is happening. Are you having issues with the insert or check? Did you remove the `md5(sha1` hashed data from db?

Comment: Hi, thank's all for your help ! @JayBlanchard problem was when i fetch the password hash from database ! and now solved, sorry for your time :)